# How to write a loop that slices a dataset by the unique values in one of the columns and iterates through a script?

Tags: r, loops, iteration

I have a df :

```
> head(df)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
           x     y     z form     
       <dbl> <int> <dbl> <list>   
1 6633000042    11 0.25  <chr [2]>
2 6633000043    11 0.978 <chr [2]>
3 6633000044    11 0.998 <chr [1]>
4 6633000057    11 0.499 <chr [2]>
5 6633000058    11 0.499 <chr [2]>
6 6633000059    11 0.329 <chr [2]>
```

The fourth column, `form`, groups the data.

What I need to do is slice this dataset into a bunch of individual datasets by the unique values in `form`, run each of those datasets through a script that stores a new column in the datasets called `c`, and then append all of those datasets back together into `df` with columns

```
> names(df)
[1] "x"    "y"    "z"    "form" "c"
```

I have tried different variations of

```
uniq <- unique(unlist(df$form))
for (i in 1:length(uniq)){
~script~
}
```

But I can't seem to get it to work... I feel like I am missing something obvious.
Any Advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something that should do want you want are at least is close enought for you to solve the task of working with the nested column in a tibble (if I understood you correctly that is):

```
library(tidyverse)

# dummy data
ndf <- tibble(x = c(1, 2, 3), 
              y = c(1, 2, 3), 
              z = list(c("a","b","c"),
                       c("a","b"),
                       "a"))

(dfl <- ndf %>%
    # "unpack" in list nested columns
    tidyr::unnest(cols = z) %>%
    # split into list of dfs of unpacked column z
    dplyr::group_split(z))

[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 3
      x     y z    
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1     1     1 a    
2     2     2 a    
3     3     3 a    

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 x 3
      x     y z    
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1     1     1 b    
2     2     2 b    

[[3]]
# A tibble: 1 x 3
      x     y z    
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1     1     1 c    

# apply custom formula on the list of dfs, in this case summation of x and y
(dfl2 <- purrr::map_df(dfl, ~.x %>%
                                dplyr::mutate(a = x + y)) %>%
    # choose which columns to nest back
    tidyr::nest(data = c(z, a)))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
      x     y data                
  <dbl> <dbl> <list>              
1     1     1 <tibble[,2] [3 x 2]>
2     2     2 <tibble[,2] [2 x 2]>
3     3     3 <tibble[,2] [1 x 2]>
```

The brakets arround the last two comands just make sure the result is printed to the console, you can delete them.

According to you comment:

```
# aproach of custom function
myfunction <- function(data){
    res <- data %>%
               dplyr::mutate(a = x + y)
    return(res)
}

# make function return NA in case of failure
myfunction <- purrr::possibly(myfunction, NA)

# apply custom formula on the list of dfs, in this case summation of x and y
purrr::map(dfl, ~myfunction(.x))

[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 4
      x     y z         a
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1     1     1 a         2
2     2     2 a         4
3     3     3 a         6

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 x 4
      x     y z         a
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1     1     1 b         2
2     2     2 b         4

[[3]]
# A tibble: 1 x 4
      x     y z         a
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1     1     1 c         2
```

You can use map() to get a list in return, what means the function output does not have to have the same df structure, you could even use models as output and work them later with map2() (takes two list inputs working the pairs, data and models ie., and gives also a list output)

Comment: Thank you @DPH ... this almost does it. My problem is, the column I want to add is a bit more complicated that what can be handled by the mutate function I believe. What my script does is takes the data you input, restructures it, applies a clustering algorithm, runs several separate calculations, chooses clusters, and spits out a tibble that is a duplicate of the data inputted with a new column that records the cluster number. It is about ~150 lines of code, and it works, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to apply it within what you have provided here. Any thoughts?

Comment: @ElijahProffitt please have a look at the altered answer - you can use your custom function/script (which as input has the df and output whatever you like... possibly even lists to combine multiple elements) for the purrr::map(), etc.

Comment: Thank you @DPH - I'm not quite there yet, but I believe I almost have everything worked out

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
uniq <- unique(unlist(df$form))
for (i in length(uniq)){
data<- df[df$form==uniq[i]]
data$c<- '''your script'''
if (i==1) final_df<- data else final_df<- rbind(final_df, data)
}
```